# Read Multiple JSONL File in python

Tags: python

Hi I have several Jsonl file with the same layout
[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO8Cv.png)

i'd like loop through the folder read every file and merge in one file.
below the code i've used, it keeps running.

````
a=[]
for filepath in glob.iglob('C:\\Users\\txb1025\\Desktop\\Perso\\Challenges\\Daltix\\Data\\*.jsonl'):
    for line in open(filepath, 'r'):
        a.append(json.loads(line))```
any help would be very appreciated
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fileinput module:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input(files=("file1", "file2")) as varname:
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html
--> read every File and put it into one single one...

I never did it with iterating over my folders and take multiple files into it but probably you can iterate over the folder and get all files in the folder into a list and pass that list

I hope this is what you want